# What is difference between qsize() and queue.unfinished_tasks for a Python Queue object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, queue

I discovered I am getting different values when checking qsize() vs the queue's unfinished_size variable.  In what cases would there be a large difference between these results?

```
   from queue import Queue
   dbjobs = Queue()
   ...
   ...
   ...
   print("qsize() = " + str(dbjobs.qsize()))
   print("unfinished_tasks = " + str(dbjobs.unfinished_tasks))
```

Example Result 1:

```
qsize() = 0
unfinished_tasks = 79
```

Example Result 2:

```
qsize() = 2
unfinished_tasks = 117
```

Comment: What Queue? What class is `dbjobs`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean the standard library's `queue.Queue` (not e.g. `asyncio.queue.Queue` or something else).

As far as I know `Queue.unfinished_tasks` is not documented, so I would advise against using it on principle.

Assuming it *does* behave as can reasonably be expected, when reading the documentation for [`Queue.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.join), the attribute `unfinished_tasks` *seems to be* a counter that goes up by one, whenever a new item is put into the queue and down by one when the [`Queue.task_done`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.task_done) method is called.

As for [`Queue.qsize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.qsize), that just returns the (approximate) number of items in the queue. Meaning that number decreases when an item is **taken out** of the queue (using [`Queue.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.get) for example). Doing that *should* have **no effect** on the `unfinished_tasks`.

You can think of it as answering different questions. The `qsize` method answers the relatively straightforward question: "How many items are in the queue right now?"

The `unfinished_tasks` counter *presumably* answers the question: "How many items that were put into the queue at some point are still in it **or are currently being worked on** by consumers of the queue?" Although this is much less precise, since it is entirely possible that a consumer of the queue takes an item out, but never calls `task_done` afterwards (because he crashed for example).